# Openshift and HtmlServiceProvider

Tags: laravel, openshift

I have pushed my local app to openshift and now get the following error message

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found in /var/lib/openshift/5728b9782d5271802600015c/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 150

How do I fix this on Openshift?

The solution locally would be to run composer update but how do I run that command on Openshift? I know there is rhc command line tool but is it possible to do a composer update with rhc?

Answer (score 0):

You should check for the files first. You may have corrupted/missing files during upload. If you do not have `vendor` directory, you shoudl run `composer update`.

If files are there, run `composer dumpauto` on the server.

You can connect to you server with SSH and run these commands from terminal.

If you do not have access to SSH, you could try to run there commands using small PHP script with `shell_exec('composer update');` clause in it, or just upload all vendor files manually.

Comment: ** dumpautoload or is that an alias?

Comment: @haakym, `dumpauto` and `dumpautoload` are aliases for `dump-autoload`

Comment: How do I run composer dumpauto on Openshift?

Answer (score 0):

I got ssh access and did the commands necessary to correct the problems